# Add to object in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add or substitute (if exist) an element in `listData` every time I use the input, but this code doesn't add the element:

```
 const [listInput, setlistInput] = useState();
 const [listData, setListData] = useState();

    useEffect(
      () => {
        requestInputData().then((data) => {   
            const lista = (data["input"].map((type) =>
            (
                <label>
                    {type}
                    <input type="text" name={type}  onChange={e => {
                       setListData({ ...listData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
                    }} /><br />
                </label>
            )
        ));
        setlistInput(lista)

        }).catch(error => {
            notification.error({
                message: APPLICATION_NAME,
                description: error.message || 'Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again!'
            });
        });
      },

      []
    );
    console.log(listData)
    return (
      <div>
     {listInput}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: JSON is a data format. You are not using JSON here.

Comment: What is the value of `listData`?

Comment: setListData({ ...listData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

Comment: listData = ["Sample id", "Sample name"]

Comment: So `listData` is an array? You are treating it like an object. Please include an example of how the value looks *before* the mutation and, given a specific input, how it should look *after* the mutation.

Comment: In general, this is the wrong way to do it. You should use state only to preserve data and be able to render content whenever that data changes. Therefore, you should 1. fetch the data from the server 2. save it to state (just the data, no elements or anything.). Your component should be able to render the state no matter if the data in the state are empty or not. I think the problem here is that you are using stalled values of listData and setListData, so you keep adding the one value to the original state over and over again.

Comment: it works but adds only one element

Comment: Yup, then it's definitely the stalled values thing. The problem is that the code within your useEffect stores a reference to setListData and listData. But every change to the state causes the value to change (not the reference in your useEffect!). So your reference in useEffect is pointing to a stalled value. Therefore you keep adding the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0):

ok work it!!! thanks.....

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([{ value: null }]);
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    function handleChange(e) {
        const values = [...fields];
        setData({
            ...data,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        setFields(values);
        console.log(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestInputData().then((data) => {
            setFields(data["input"]);

        }).catch(error => {
            notification.error({
                message: APPLICATION_NAME,
                description: error.message || 'Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again!'
            });
        });
    }, []
    )

    return (
        <div >

            {fields.map((field) => {
                return (
                    <div >

                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name={field}
                            placeholder={field}
                            onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
                        /> 
                        <br/>

                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
```